# How to enable hostname resolving in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, host-name-resolution

I have installed Debian on a dedicated server. The company that leases this server gave me 3 addresses:

- DMZ IP
- Mask
- Gateway

The server cannot resolve hostnames. So when I use ping with IP- it works. When I use ping with hostname- it doesn't. 
I think I should put something in

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

But I don't know what. Should it be the gateway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a gateway is a router. You'll want to specify name servers. For example:

```
nameserver 209.244.0.3
nameserver 209.244.0.4
```

Or whichever name servers you want to use. Your hosting provider probably has name servers very, very close to your server. Those might be the best option, and you should ask them the IP addresses of their name servers for your use. Or use a search engine to find publicly available name servers. My hosts are very close to Level 3, so I use the Level 3 name servers, as specified above.

Another nice option is the `search` or `domain` option. From the manual (`man resolv.conf`):

> domain Local domain name.
>                 Most  queries for names within this domain can use short names relative to the local domain.  If set to
>                 '.', the root domain is considered.  If no domain entry is present, the domain is determined  from  the
>                 local  hostname  returned  by gethostname(2); the domain part is taken to be everything after the first
>                 '.'.  Finally, if the hostname does not contain a domain part, the root domain is assumed.
>
> search Search list for host-name lookup.
>                 The search list is normally determined from the local domain name; by default,  it  contains  only  the
>                 local  domain name.  This may be changed by listing the desired domain search path following the search
>                 keyword with spaces or tabs separating the names.   Resolver  queries  having  fewer  than  ndots  dots
>                 (default  is 1) in them will be attempted using each component of the search path in turn until a match
>                 is found.  For environments with multiple subdomains please read options ndots:n below to avoid man-in-
>                 the-middle  attacks  and  unnecessary  traffic for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this process may be
>                 slow and will generate a lot of network traffic if the servers for the listed domains  are  not  local,
>                 and that queries will time out if no server is available for one of the domains.
>
> The search list is currently limited to six domains with a total of 256 characters.

```
domain your-domain-name.com
nameserver 209.244.0.3
nameserver 209.244.0.4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly! I've installed Debian a few times and I never had this problem before so I thought something is wrong on the company side.